# Flexbox isn't lining up boxes properly in Safari

Tags: css, safari, html, flexbox

I am trying to create a two column layout using `flex`. [Here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tfFyA/) showing what I currently have. It works just like I want it to in Chrome and Firefox. However, in Safari, each `div` expands to fill the whole whole window, and the second wraps so that it's one on top of the other. I want them both next to each other.

TL;DR: [Code/demo are here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tfFyA/). Works in Chrome, Firefox. Doesn't work in Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. The issue is that Safari needs a vendor-specific prefix for it to work. So if I add a `display: -webkit-flex;` to the `flexbox` and a `-webkit-flex: auto;` to each of the `div`s, it works as intended. Dontcha just love CSS browser support?

Here's a [working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bogxy/).